# Different zoom, for each android device

Tags: java, android, matrix, zooming

I wrote class to changing bitmap zoom. I'm basing on MotionEvent and matrix class. I want to read scale and by calculating it, show real dimensions. And i'm testing it on different devices, problem is, that minimum zoom on each device is different.

```
private void zoom(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    final float newDistance = spacing(event);
    if (newDistance > 10f) {
        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
        float scale = newDistance / oldDistance;
        final float[] values = new float[9];
        matrix.getValues(values);
        final float currentScaleX = values[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
        if (scale * currentScaleX > MAX_ZOOM)
            scale = MAX_ZOOM / currentScaleX;
        else if (scale * currentScaleX < MIN_ZOOM)
            scale = MIN_ZOOM / currentScaleX;

        final float height = Math.round(imageHeight / (metrics.density * currentScaleX * scale));

        if (height >= (IMAGE_HEIGHT*NUMBER_TO_CHANGE_ZOOM) ) {
            scale = imageHeight / (IMAGE_HEIGHT*NUMBER_TO_CHANGE_ZOOM * metrics.density) / currentScaleX;
        }

        zoom = currentScaleX * scale;
        readScaleOfImage();
        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
        check(view, event);
    }
}
```

This method change zoom of image by matrix.

This is spacing mehtod, to count zoom, i have no idea, how it works.

```
private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    return (float) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}
```

Can anyone help how to know how small will be zoom value?